# Flutter: How to wait for WebView to finish loading after running JavaScript function and display the html?

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-inappwebview

I wanted to get the finished loaded website's HTML code from my headlessWebView but initially, the website executes some js.

The steps to get what I want is:

1. Open the website,
2. Run javascript function to fill some content on a textfield and press submit,
3. Wait for the website to execute the js and finish loading,
4. Store the results of the webview as HTML code in a string.

This is my code below:

```
     final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

     InAppWebViewGroupOptions options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
     crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
        useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
      ),
      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
        useHybridComposition: true,
      ),
      ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
      ));

      HeadlessInAppWebView headlessWebView;
      String htmlCode = "";

      @override
      void initState() {
      super.initState();

      headlessWebView = new HeadlessInAppWebView(
      initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(URL: 
      Uri.parse("https://example.com/")),
      initialOptions: options,
      /*InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
        crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(),
      ),*/
      shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
        var uri = navigationAction.request;
        headlessWebView.webViewController.loadUrl(urlRequest: uri);
        return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
      },
      onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
        print('HeadlessInAppWebView created!');
      },
      onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
        print("CONSOLE MESSAGE: " + consoleMessage.message);
      },
      onLoadStart: (controller, url) async {
        print("onLoadStart $url");
        setState(() {
          this.url = url.toString();
        });
      },
      onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
        print("onLoadStop $url");
        String jsscript =
            "javascript:(function() { document.getElementById(\"text_feild\").value ='" +
                "sometext" +
                "';document.getElementById(\"submit\").click();})();";
        await headlessWebView.webViewController
            .evaluateJavascript(source: jsscript);

        var result = await headlessWebView.webViewController.evaluateJavascript(
            source:
                "javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('a')[5].getAttribute('href').outerHTML;");

        log(result.toString());
        htmlCode = result.toString();
    
      },
      onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
        print("onUpdateVisitedHistory $url");
        setState(() {
          this.url = url.toString();
        });
      },
    );
```

I get an error in the log(result.toString()); It is always null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the HTML in the string I'm currently using that is my app it works fine.

```
onLoadStop:
                  (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {
                print("onLoadStop: " + url);
                var html = await controller.evaluateJavascript(
                    source:
                        "window.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;");
}
```